# jquery toggle & hide others

Tags: jquery

I've been learning jQuery, and I'm trying to get a little list going that I can hide and show stuff based on a click. I have it set up to the point where I can click to expand and it'll close all others and expand the correct one, but unfortunately I can't figure out how to make it close by clicking again (which I thought toggle would do).

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".expand").click(function() {
        $(".rating-container").hide();
        $(this).find(".rating-container").toggle();
    });
});
```

Thanks for any help you guys can provide!

http://jsfiddle.net/pDALQ/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Hide all the *other* ratings containers first (`$('.expand').not(this).find(".rating-container").hide()`).

Try:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".expand").click(function () {
        $('.expand').not(this).find(".rating-container").hide();
        $(this).find(".rating-container").toggle();
    });
});
```

**[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/j08691/pDALQ/3/)**

Answer (score 0):

Because you are hiding the containers first, the toggle will not work. Here is another method to do it -

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(".expand").click(function() {
        if( $(this).find(".rating-container").is(':visible') ) {
            $(".rating-container").hide();
        } else {
            $(".rating-container").hide();
            $(this).find(".rating-container").show();
        }
    });
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/jayblanchard/pDALQ/4/